# Get The Data based on start date and date date

Tags: python, django

I have 2 DB tables:
1. order table which has Tickets table with time field for ticket_date. 
2. Customer table which also has foreign key relationship with assignee (Manager)table like each customer has start date and end date for assignee to manager.
If I want to get Data using ORM in Django like 
How many ticket closed buy assignee(Manager)

I just wanted to pick Start date end date of reporting date over the given date range

Customer reporting from 1 to 10th of month with manganer M1 in this span he placed 2 order and after 10th of the month reporting manger changes to M2 and placed order 4 
So how I can make sure it’s not counted for whole date range

Comment: Did you made any attempt?

Comment: Yes but not able to filter in internal reporting dates

Comment: @MayankPratapSingh Post your current query and then take a look through the lookups available here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups